# Cutout a polygon from another in any layer in Eagle CAD part creation

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, eaglecad, pad

I am trying to create a part with a bespoke pad. How do I cut one polygon (for where the hole will be) from the original pad polygon. I don't just want to make a dimension layer and let the PCB house cut through the pad, or is that the right/only way to do it? Couldn't find any ranks for the polygons nor a restrict layer that works for pads?

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Talk to your board house.  Don't assume you know the best way for them to handle this.

Basically you seem to be asking for a plated-thru milled hole.  The first answer is to avoid that.  If you really can't, the second answer is to ask the board house how to specify it.  There are different processes, and it depends when the plating is done relative to the routing.  This may require a additional routing step, which may cost extra.  Again, see the first answer.